# Looking for Andengine 64bit version

Tags: android, 64-bit, andengine

Google developer console requests my Andengine based Android game to be uploaded in both 32bit and 64bit versions. see here: [Get your apps ready for the 64-bit requirement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html)

So i am **looking for a libandengine.so in 64bit** so i can build my 64bit compliant apk.

If anyone successfully acquired the 64 bit .so , please send me - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libandengine.so` file contains just 2 classes `GLES20Fix` and `BufferUtils` , here [they are](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/tree/GLES2/jni/src). Here are java classes [GLES20Fix.java](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/opengl/GLES20Fix.java)  and  [BufferUtils.java](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/opengl/util/BufferUtils.java) which call classes from `libandengine.so`. As you can see from java source code and comments C-classes contains workarounds for system bugs [11078](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11078), [16941](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16941), [8931](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8931)  which were in Android 2.2 (froyo), Android 3.0 (honeycomb) and Android 3.2 (honeycomb_mr2).

So, if you don't support android 2.x and 3.x devices you should just delete all `libandengine.so` files from your project. We did so with our project about year ago,  everything works ok.

Comment: You are awesome! thanks! i have removed them as advised and works like charm! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any libs, then create copy for 64bit too.. i.e your lib directory 
contains any of X86 then itshould contains X86_64
or armeabi/v71 then v8a also.

And in Module.gradle file, in defaultconfig attribute add files for 64 bit like :

```
 ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips","x86_64","armeabi-v8a"
        }
```

Comment: exactly it should, but it isnt, i could not find the 64 bit version of the lib anwhere on net, that is he problem.

Comment: just create the folder in lib with the respective name and copy past the content .